# Error handling in vbscript?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, error-handling

There is some old legacy vbscript code we have that needs some sort of error handing in it.  Having never used vbscript before, I'm at a total loss.  Here is the code:

```
set objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkload.4.0")
objBL.ConnectionString = "connectionstring"
objBL.KeepIdentity = false
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "E:\code\Acquity\WebOrderImport\logs\error.log"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set parentfolder = fso.GetFolder("E:\textdata\Acquity\AcquityWebOrders")  
Set logfile = fso.OpenTextFile("E:\code\Acquity\WebOrderImport\logs\import.log",8)
count = 0
    For each folder in parentfolder.subfolders
        logfile.writeline count & " files"
        logfile.writeline "Processing " & folder.name & " ***********************************" & now()
        count = 1
        For Each file in folder.files
            If left(file.name,6) = "Order_" then
                If left(file.name,13) = previous then
                    logfile.writeline "!!!!! SKIPPING file " & file.name & "!!!!! DUPED ORDER ID"
                Else
                    logfile.writeline "reading " & file.name        
                    objBL.Execute "E:\code\Acquity\WebOrderImport\acq_WebOrder_import.xsd", file.path                   
                    count=count+1
                End If  
            previous = left(file.name,13)
            End If
        Next
    Next    

set objBL=Nothing
logfile.writeline "Done!"
Set logfile = nothing
Set parentfolder = nothing
set fso = nothing
```

I'm pretty sure this line:

```
bjBL.Execute "E:\code\Acquity\WebOrderImport\acq_WebOrder_import.xsd", file.path
```

keeps throwing exceptions, and I need the code to keep running when it hits an error, rather than stopping.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore errors, add `On Error Resume Next` before the part that can cause them. To disable the effect of "resume next", use `On Error Goto 0`.

Comment: You can learn more about error trapping in VBScript by reading my article over at ASP Free. http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Error-Trapping-and-Capturing-ThirdParty-Output-in-WSH/

Answer (score 3):

For a quick and (very) dirty way to get the code to keep running, you can add `On Error Resume Next` to the top of the file, and execution will happily carry on when it hits an error.

Answer (score 2):

I have a little practice with this technology, but AFAIK vbscript has only one way to handle runtime-exceptions: `On Error Resume Next`.

You can read these articles: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163845%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and more helpful for me [about handling and notifying.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/c_vbscript_err_hndlng.htm)